# Update Query issue . 0 rows updated when there should have been 1. HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I have a table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `MW_Locations`  CHANGE COLUMN `ID` `ID` INT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL FIRST,    CHANGE COLUMN `UDID` `UDID` INT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `ID`,   CHANGE COLUMN `IDACCOUNT` `IDACCOUNT` INT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `UDID`,   CHANGE COLUMN `Name` `Name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `IDACCOUNT`,    CHANGE COLUMN `Lat` `Lat` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `Name`,    CHANGE COLUMN `Lon` `Lon` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `Lat`,     CHANGE COLUMN `IDMWDevice` `IDMWDevice` INT(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `Lon`,  CHANGE COLUMN `Desc` `Desc` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `IDMWDevice`,   CHANGE COLUMN `IDAction` `IDAction` INT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `Desc`,     CHANGE COLUMN `Status` `Status` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `IDAction`,     ADD PRIMARY KEY (`IDACCOUNT`);
```

The issue is I can´t make any update.Like this one:

```
UPDATE `MW_Locations` SET `IDACCOUNT`=1 WHERE  `ID`=0 AND `UDID`=0 AND `IDACCOUNT`=0 AND `Name`='Panteon' AND `Lat`=25.6789521128695 AND `Lon`=100.336310863495 AND `IDMWDevice`=0 AND `Desc`='' AND `IDAction`=0 AND `Status`='' LIMIT 1;
```

Im using heidisql connecting to a server 
The rows I have made are these ones:[image]

Want to make all the rows I have of the column IDACCOUNT with the value "1" So it would be assigned to a user 1 in my database, later bring in a json that array of data to make some tasks. Also I want to make ID increment but it brings me an error too.

Comment: Why is this tagged `jquery`?

Comment: The alter table statement should have failed too. The column `IDACCOUNT` can't be the sole `PRIMARY KEY` column with the displayed data.

Comment: sorry mah mistake it was query

Comment: I think I understand the issue now: you've got to update the values in this column first to create the `primary key` that you want.

Comment: Exactly. HeidiSQL sees the table has no primary or unique key, so it generates a messy `UPDATE` command with all columns in place, including inexact values from floats. It's highly recommended to create a primary key if you want to edit data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query fails, because you demand exact equality for your `DOUBLE` fields `Lat` and `Lon`. Those columns are not needed to identify your row. Rewrite your sql statement to

```
UPDATE `MW_Locations` 
   SET `IDACCOUNT`=1 
 WHERE `Name`='Panteon';
```

This value in this column is enough to identify your row.

I cite from [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html):

> Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact
>   values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to
>   problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when we edit a table that has a JSON field, the update does not find the record for the update

That's mostly caused by a missing primary or unique key.
add a primary key to that table

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you have a trigger for that table on update. If fields you are trying to SET are calculated by a trigger on update, you always receive that error and never are updated.